# Traverse a string of dictionary and store as single dictionary in python

Tags: python, regex, dictionary

I have a sample string that looks like dictionary but contains value which has double quotes and comma in it which makes it difficult to be read using json.loads. I am writing code to find an element and extract its value till "," is found and store it as list so the data can be converted to dataframe.

example:

```
filtered_data = '''[
   {
      "_id":"1231",
      "address":"akjd-dfdkfj",
      "body":"Your one time password is "sdkd". Enter this in the form to confirm your value.",
      "date":"Thu May 10 23:34:11 GMT+05:30 2018"
   },
   {
      "_id":"1245",
      "address":"sdsd-dgfg",
      "body":"Dear Customer, Reference number is 3435.To check latest status, sms DROP DFGDG on 38388338. Thank you, ABC",
      "date":"Thu May 10 13:22:54 GMT+05:30 2018"
   }
]'''
```

Code written so far:

```
import re
id_locs  = [(m.start(0), m.end(0)) for m in re.finditer('_id', filtered_data)]
```

How to extract value by specifying end string as ","?

expected output:

```
{
    "_id": [
        "1231",
        "1245"
    ],
    "_address": [
        "akjd-dfdkfj",
        "sdsd-dgfg"
    ],
    "body": [
        "Your one time password is 'sdkd'. Enter this in the form to confirm your value.",
        "Dear Customer, Reference number is 3435.To check latest status, sms DROP DFGDG on 38388338. Thank you, ABC"
    ],
    "date": [
        "Thu May 10 23:34:11 GMT+05:30 2018",
        "Thu May 10 13:22:54 GMT+05:30 2018"
    ]
}
```

Comment: thanks jon, tried that before and it says invalid syntax

Comment: You've deleted triple quotes mistakenly. Bring them back.

Comment: Are you sure that original source string contains `Your one time password is "sdkd".` instead of `Your one time password is \"sdkd\".`?

Comment: yes, that's the problem and this is present in a txt file and can't be altered from original source. This is causing all the trouble to parse this string. Plus there are about 25 million such files so can't edit them manually as well.

Comment: @user3222101 do the actual files contain new lines? Because making it a multiline string now - I'm not sure if that's for presentation purposes to make it easier for us to read, or whether you really do have files with just single lines?

Comment: Oliver formatted it for readability purpose otherwise the text comes in one line example format is :{"SMS":[{"_id":.... } and i just extracted text after SMS and stored it in filtered_data

Comment: @user3222101, I have no idea, which software can produce json ouitput violating JSON standarts. Maybe better to do something with input and then just serialize json?

Comment: You should put **exact** same input (no new lines, or with new lines) in the question, because depends on the format, regex can be very different

Comment: What do you have in the file after all, `\"sdkd\"`, `"sdkd"` or `'sdkd'`?

Comment: @tevemadar : "sdkd"

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the non-escaped quotation marks occur only in `"body"`-lines, it can be fixed into a proper JSON, and parsed afterwards. Then you have a task of reshaping a list of dicts into a dict of lists.

```
import json,re

filtered_data = '''[
   {
      "_id":"1231",
      "address":"akjd-dfdkfj",
      "body":"Your one time password is "sdkd". Enter this in the form to confirm your value.",
      "date":"Thu May 10 23:34:11 GMT+05:30 2018"
   },
   {
      "_id":"1245",
      "address":"sdsd-dgfg",
      "body":"Dear Customer, Reference number is 3435.To check latest status, sms DROP DFGDG on 38388338. Thank you, ABC",
      "date":"Thu May 10 13:22:54 GMT+05:30 2018"
   }
]'''

corrected_data=re.sub("^\s*\"body\":\"(.*)\",",lambda x:"\"body\":\""+x.group(1).replace("\"","'")+"\",",filtered_data,flags=re.M)
dicts_in_list=json.loads(corrected_data)
lists_in_dict={key:[item[key] for item in dicts_in_list] for key in dicts_in_list[0].keys() }
print(lists_in_dict)
```

Comment: Yours input differs from input provided in question.

Comment: @OlvinRoght: nope, he says the data actually comes from a file, it is just an example posted in the question.

Comment: Nope. Your string: `password is \\"sdkd\\".`, original: `password is "sdkd".`

Comment: @OlvinRoght: I copied the text from the question. It contained ```\```s originally. I will ask...

Answer (score 0):

If the string would form a valid json document, you can use (you probably just need to add '[' and ']' at the beginning / end of the string:

```
import json
str2="""[{"_id":"1231","address":"akjd-dfdkfj","body": "Your one time password is sdkd. Enter this in the form to confirm your value.","date":"Thu May 10 23:34:11 GMT+05:30 2018"},{"_id":"1245","address":"sdsd-dgfg","body":"Dear Customer, Reference number is 3435.To check latest status, sms DROP DFGDG on 38388338. Thank you, ABC","date":"Thu May 10 13:22:54 GMT+05:30 2018"}]"""
>>> json.loads(str2, encoding='UTF8')
result_dicts=json.loads(str2)
```

And then "merge" the dictionaries together into one, like this:

```
result_dict= dict()
for res_dict in result_dicts:
    for key, value in res_dict.items():
        result_dict.setdefault(key, list()).append(value)
```

But if your example string really looks like in your description, it is not a valid json string, because of the improper use of doublequotes (e.g. in "Your one time password is "sdkd". Enter this in the form to confirm your value."), you need to parse it yourself.

To apply regex you need to make some assumptions to cut the string in valid pieces. E.g. is it safe to assume, that a field value is always doublequoted?
Or can you assume, that a field value never contains the chararcter combinations <",> and <"}> (I use <> to limit the string)?

If so, you can build your regex in such a way, that it cuts out substrings delimited by one of these strings to get the field name and field value. Without such assumptions, you cannot solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A solution with regular expressions would look like:

```
patt=re.compile('"([^"]*)"\s*:\s*"(.*?)"(,|\s*\})', re.MULTILINE)
result_dict=dict()
at_end= False
pos= 0
while not at_end:
    matcher= patt.search(filtered_data, pos= pos)
    at_end= matcher is None
    if not at_end:
        key, value, _= matcher.groups()
        result_dict.setdefault(key, list()).append(value)
        _, pos= matcher.span()
```

The assumption is, that a key, value pair always ends in '",' or '"\s*}' as in your example data.

With findall it looks a bit more compact:

```
patt=re.compile('"([^"]*)"\s*:\s*"(.*?)"(,|\s*\})', re.MULTILINE)
result_dict=dict()
for key, value, sep in patt.findall(filtered_data):
    result_dict.setdefault(key, list()).append(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach using Regex. Get values using `lookahead & lookbehind`

**Ex:**

```
import re

filtered_data = '''[
   {
      "_id":"1231",
      "address":"akjd-dfdkfj",
      "body":"Your one time password is "sdkd". Enter this in the form to confirm your value.",
      "date":"Thu May 10 23:34:11 GMT+05:30 2018"
   },
   {
      "_id":"1245",
      "address":"sdsd-dgfg",
      "body":"Dear Customer, Reference number is 3435.To check latest status, sms DROP DFGDG on 38388338. Thank you, ABC",
      "date":"Thu May 10 13:22:54 GMT+05:30 2018"
   }
]'''
keys = set(re.findall(r'\"(.+)\":', filtered_data))   #Get Keys
result = {}
for key in keys:
    result[key] = re.findall(r'(?<=\"{}":\")(.*?)(?=\",?)'.format(key), filtered_data)   #Get Values.

print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
{'_id': ['1231', '1245'],
 'address': ['akjd-dfdkfj', 'sdsd-dgfg'],
 'body': ['Your one time password is ',
          'Dear Customer, Reference number is 3435.To check latest status, sms '
          'DROP DFGDG on 38388338. Thank you, ABC'],
 'date': ['Thu May 10 23:34:11 GMT+05:30 2018',
          'Thu May 10 13:22:54 GMT+05:30 2018']}
```